# Excel - is there a keyboard shortcut to select/highlight a part of a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, vba

If you edit a formula in Excel, Excel helpfully shows the parameters of the formula, as well as which parameter you are currently looking at. E.g. if you type "=INDEX(" Excel will show "INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])". If you click on one of these the section highlights and then press F9 it calculates that piece of the formula.

I can begin the editing with F2 and calculate the piece with F9, but is there a keyboard shortcut to "click on the whole piece you are now in"?

If this can be accomplished in vba what would be the relevant methods to trigger this behavior?

Comment: This can be achieved by VBA macro,,, if U are comfortable with it please [edit] your post and mention your need as well add new TAG ,, VBA to the post!

Comment: What's the meaning of ""click on the whole piece you are now in""?? Could you provide more information about it?

Comment: @Lee, in my INDEX example above, you can click "array" and it highlights the first part of your input completely, and then if you click F9 it calculates just that highlighted part.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing I know of that is able to select the whole parameter with a single key combo.

However, Excel DOES let you use Ctrl-Right Arrow and Ctrl-Left Arrow and they can combine with Shift in the standard Windows manner.

So, if at the beginning of a parameter, one could press Ctrl-Shift-Right Arrow and expect Excel to highlight the parameter.

Of course, there are two difficulties with that. One is that Excel actually highlights to the next punctuation character (to the side of it it began on, so if starting to its left, it highlights to the left side of the next punctuation character). For many things entered as parameters, that's fine. Look where you are (IN the parameter? At its left? Its right?) and act accordingly. For instance, say the parameter is the word `FALSE` as the fourth parameter in a `VLOOKUP()`. You might be between the "A" and the "L". You could press Ctrl-Left Arrow to get to the parameter's start, then Ctrl-Shift-Right Arrow to highlight to its end.

The complication comes when something like a range is specified. Anything with punctuation in it, but especially ranges as they are very common. So in that case you have to do more, and pay more attention. Easiest is to go to the end you're on with Ctrl-Appropriate Arrow and then use Ctrl-Shift-Other Arrow to move bit by bit to the start of the parameter. Easy, but more involved.

Another complication is that Excel will not handle double quotation marks (`"`, used for parameter entries that are strings, or involve strings (like `"="&A2` in certain xxxIF functions)) in the same manner. So you have a string like `"kjsdhfks"` and are somewhere in it. Ctrl-Left Arrow comes to the right of the starting `"` but another press takes you into the preceding parameter, not just to its left. So you get to the right of it, then press Left Arrow on its own and begin the Ctrl-Shift-Right Arrow-ing until you reach its end, then just Shift-Right Arrow to include the right-side `"` in the highlighting.

Excel also treats the space in the same manner as general punctuation. Occasional other bits are handled like the double quote character (a negative sign, for example). You just have to pay attention more than you might like.

So if you have a nice gaming keyboard that can build key macros and that's why you asked the question, do it. It should work a fair amount, and you can see if it does a given instance right, then hand-do it yourself if it didn't. Might work and be slick, if not, well, you had to do it by hand anyway, right?

Also, the punctuation thing can be tricky in importance as doing the `F9` thing often requires inclusion of parentheses but not always (if you included one, you need the other;  if not, you don't) and Excel treats them like the `"` so it takes attention while doing it.